# All new revision fail on Cloud Run for a single region. "Unable to create 0 instances for "XXX" because there are already 0 in this region"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have 2 services running on GCP. Everytime the source repos is updated a new revision is deployed by a gitlab pipeline with the following command:

`gcloud run deploy api-demo --project <my_project_name> --region europe-west1 --image $API_IMAGE:latest`

It was working fine until today but now it is impossible to create new revision on Cloud Run for the region **europe-west1**. Every time I try to create a new revision the status of the revision is pending for about 15 minutes then the status is updated to **"Unable to create 0 instances for "<name_of_the_revision>" because there are already 0 in this region."**

I am the owner of the project so I don't think it's a permission probleme.
I looked at my quotat and there are none above 20% so that shouln't be the problem either.
According to [GCP status](https://status.cloud.google.com/regional/europe) there are no incident currently.

Any idea of what could be the source of the errors?

1. I tried to create revision manually from the web console, it gave me the same error.
2. I tried to create a new service in the same region with the hello exemple image, it gave me the same error.
3. I tried to copy my service to another region (europe-west12) and it worked this time.

Comment: Did you reach the support?

Comment: Yes but all that is availble is bot that "couldn’t find any matching answers for your query."

Comment: The probleme didn't go away so I had to migrate to europe-west4 but now the same thing is happening in europe-west4. I didn't even had the time to update my CI pipeline, so I least I it doesn't come from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278096734

Basicly the max number of instance that could scale on that reagion was superior to 10 and because of that the quota "Cloud Run: maximum instance per region" was triggered even if only 2 instances were running and **despite it not being shown as such**.

So reducing the maximum number of instance or increasing the quota solve the probleme.